# wit.ai messenger bot with yes or no reply

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I'm starting with [wit.ai](http://wit.ai), I'm trying to create a simple messenger bot, I have everything working on facebook but I'm struggling with a simple task how to make the bot reply a different phrase based on the response given by the user.

Example:

> User: Hello 
>   Bot: Hi, Do you want to listen a joke?
>
> User: Yes 
>   Bot: [Tell a Joke]
>
> or
>
> User: No 
>   Bot: Ok bye bye!

This seems to be very simple but I'm struggling with it. Some one can make an example how to make this?

Note: I know that there are a doc about this issue on [wit.ai documentation](https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#handle-yesno-answers), but even with that information I can't put this simple bot working.

Answer (score 5):

The recipe can definitely be better...

You will find below how to [train the yes/no entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhzCE.gif)

We are working on a simpler way to do that with branching and it will come soon. Follow your roadmap here: https://github.com/wit-ai/wit

Comment: Here is a concrete public example you can look at: https://wit.ai/l5t/BotEngine_YesNo_Example/stories

Comment: Thanks. I think you should create an official slack channel for wit.ai.
And maybe create a real live example of a facebook bot (is trending at the moment), a simple thing without use external apis only hardcoded functions. And do a video tutorial explaining the process.  
Most of the times the problems appear when we use multiple stories and multiple entities.

Comment: @FábioFerreira did you end up creating a wit.ai slack channel? would like to be a part of the conversation :D